# selected index of dropdown getting losing to zero after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net dropdown ,with enableviewstate to false
I am binding that dropdown in pageload without using ispostback.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              binddropdown();
        }
```

I have set enableviewstate to false since i check lot of viewstate information is store in hidden field.due to which page render slowly.

when i change dropdown selected item and click on submit button.dropdownlist selectedindex loose,since at pageload i am binding dropdown.

How can i efficiently use viewstate and pagelifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that since you have disabled the `ViewState` of your dropdown it is not able to retain the items and on each postback items are getting populated (obviously we will have to as you are already doing). Since items are added again your dropdown is getting reset again and you are not able to get the selected value.

IMHO you should not disable the `ViewState` of your dropdown. But if you have already then you can set the selected value using the forms collection like this:-

Just bind the dropdown on initial page load:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    binddropdown();
    if(IsPostBack)
     {
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
     }   
 }
```